# angularJS $scope.$watch not working when input box becomes empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started with AngularJS and I'm trying to share data between two ng-controllers (both controllers are in the same ng-app module) using a factory. Data(HTML input field) from controller1 seems to get shared with controller2 most of the times; but when I delete all contents of the input field, the $watch doesn't seem to work! I'm finding it a little hard to explain in words. The screenshots below might help.

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
  </head>

  <body class="container" ng-app='myApp'>

    <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
        <br>
        Input is : <strong>{{firstName}}</strong>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
        Input should also be here: {{firstName}}
    </div>


    <script>

        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.factory('Data', function () {
            var data = {
              FirstName: ''
            }

            return {
              getFirstName: function () {
                  return data.FirstName;
              },
              setFirstName: function (x) {
                  data.FirstName = x;
              }
            }
        });

        myApp.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.firstName = ''

            $scope.$watch('firstName', function(newVal){
              if(newVal){Data.setFirstName(newVal);}
            });
        });

        myApp.controller('ctrl2', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.$watch(function(){return Data.getFirstName();}, function(newVal){
              if(newVal){$scope.firstName = newVal;}
            });
        });
    </script>

  </body>

  <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
  </footer>
</html>
```

There's also a jsfiddle I found for this code. http://jsfiddle.net/5LL3U/2/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is based on an example in one of my old answers and it's wrong. So I apologize and will update it :) It should use `oldValue` and do: `if (newValue !== oldValue)`

Comment: Thank you @tasseKATT. Keep up the good work! cheers :)

Comment: And thanks for noticing the error :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check both newValue with oldValue for this.In case of empty newValue it is not calling your factory and will not set the value on the variable. :-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    var data =
        {
            FirstName: ''
        };

    return {
        getFirstName: function () {
            return data.FirstName;
        },
        setFirstName: function (firstName) {
            data.FirstName = firstName;
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ) {

    $scope.firstName = '';

    $scope.$watch('firstName', function (newValue,oldValue) {
        console.log(oldValue+"   "+newValue);
        if (newValue!=oldValue) Data.setFirstName(newValue);
    });
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){

    $scope.$watch(function () { return Data.getFirstName(); }, function (newValue,oldValue) {
        if (newValue!=oldValue) $scope.firstName = newValue;
    });
});
```

Fiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/1d1vL1hd/

Comment: It is a watch, so newValue will always be different than oldValue!

Comment: but if(newValue) is not going to call Data.setFirstName(newValue) in case of newValue is null

Comment: Your condition will always pass, so no need to have one. If one wants to check if the value is null or undefined, then the condition needs to be updated.

Comment: Should probably use `!==` instead of `!=` until you know that you really need type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is wrong. When empty, newValue is falsy and firstName doesn't get updated.

```
function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) Data.setFirstName(newValue);
});
```

So you need to change or remove your condition.

Answer (score 1):

$scope.$watch('object', function(new, old){
}, **true**);

The true here is for object equality...like this watch is triggered always on value change

Also, to share data between controllers use a service not a factory.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  just remove checking `if (newValue)` from your code.

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5LL3U/200/)

Answer (score 0):

just change this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-trim="false">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twt2nbpL/#&togetherjs=53GqpR44vP